# Question about using CreateWizard and Login Controls as opposed to starting from scratch

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am just learning C# ASP.NET, when I create a project in visual studio, the login controls and CreateWizard is standard.  Do many ADVANCED programmers use these things or do they just build from scratch?  If you dont use this as your login method, how are you sure that you will take all the correct security measures of being hacked, sql injection etc etc.?  I feel like  its easy to use the login controls and createwizard, i couldnt see why anyone else would not use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it can take more effort to learn how to use these prebuilt controls at the start, but with them you gain the advantage of using proven industry standards, built in validation, etc.

Often a custom solution can overlook possible bugs. The built in controls have likely be more throughly tested then any testing that could be done to any custom controls that are created, with known bugs being well documented and likely already found within the community.

These controls should not be thought of as closed solutions as a lot of these controls are built to be easily extended by the use of the provider patterns (such as the [Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx)), [theming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx) and [templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h59db326.aspx), allowing for custom functionality when needed.

Answer (score 0):

In all my recent projects, I've just created both pages from scratch.

Part of it is that I want more control over how my pages look, and part of it is my mentality where I often find it easier to just do something my way rather than refreshing myself on how those controls work.

By default, ASP.NET pages raise an exception if fields are submitted with HTML codes. However, even this is not an issue. Just make sure you run any user-entered text through `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` whenever you display it on a page.